# Hashie::Rash element access

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

New to working with Hashie::Rash.  I understand how to access elements in the "results" section of the following hashie, but how can I access the "count" element before the "results" in the following example:

```
hashie => #<Hashie::Rash count=20 page=1 results=[#<Hashie::Rash customer=#<Hashie::Rash addresses=[] custom_external_id="58749" emails=[#<Hashie::Rash email=#<Hashie::Rash created_at="2013-02-13T15:59:26-08:00" email="CENSORED" id=33622514 updated_at="2013-02-13T15:59:26-08:00" verified_at=nil>>] first_name="CENSORED" id=68712186 language=nil last_name="CENSORED" phones=[#<Hashie::Rash phone=#<Hashie::Rash created_at="2013-02-13T16:00:45-08:00" id=1301079 phone="CENSORED" updated_at="2013-02-13T16:00:45-08:00">>] twitters=[nil]>>, #<Hashie::Rash customer=#<Hashie::Rash addresses=[] custom_external_id="58749"  emails=[] first_name="CENSORED" id=71095620 language=nil last_name="CENSORED" phones=[] twitters=[nil]>>] total=2>
```

Comment: Call `.count` on your `Hashie::Rash` object

Comment: I updated the code to call the hasie:rash object "hashie."  Can you be a little more specific on how to call "count" (20) element? When I run `.count` I just get the number of hashies, not the count=20 that I'm trying to access.  `hashie.count` returns 9.

Comment: That doesn't seem to work.  Also tried doing `hashie.to_h` to call that count=20 but still can't figure it out.

Comment: `hashie.attributes` returns `nil`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Hashie::Rash` still acts like a `Hash` for many things so `#count` still uses `Hash#count` which you can see with your result being 9.

```
hashie = Hashie::Rash.new({count:20, page: 1, results:["a","b","c"]})
#=> #<Hashie::Rash count=20 page=1 results=["a", "b", "c"]>
hashie.count #uses Hash#count
#=> 3
```

but since `Hashie::Rash` is at its cores still a `Hash` (just with Truely Indifferent Access) it also maintains quite a few based methods for access such as `Hash#[]`

```
hashie['count']
#=> 20
hashie[:count]
#=> 20
hashie['page'] == hashie.page
#=> true
```

Your answer works as well because `Hash#values` returns an `Array` but this seems like an unnecessary step and lacks readability and manageability.

Answer (score 0):

Not particularly eloquent, but in the above example,

`hashie.values[1]` returns `20`

Hope this helps someone else someday.

Comment: `Hashie::Rash` still acts like a `Hash` for many things so `#count` still uses `Hash#count` which you can see with result being 9. But `hashie['count']` will return 20 since `Hashie::Rash` still supports the `Hash#[key]` style syntax.

Comment: @engineersmnky Yep!  You're absolutely right.  Maybe you should add that as answer?